# Issues with state is being reset to initial state when parent state is updated (dynamic form made with multiple components)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

Github link:
https://github.com/dampbacon/reactjs_prototype/tree/dev

## **Background:**

I'm creating a web app to make marker rubrics using a dynamic form (and eventually marking with it).
The general gist is that you add a question(currently reading just a template json), and each question is a component which had blocks with fields you can add or remove. Which will eventually get submitted

The rubric container has **DATA** that contains the questions in some json format.

```
const DATA = 
[
    {question_id:1, question_title:'how to abc', 
    rubric_fields : 
         [{text: "blahblah", grade: 3 },
          {text: "blahblah", grade: 3 },
          {text: "blahblah", grade: 4 }]},
    {question_id:2, question_title:'how to eat an apple', 
    rubric_fields : 
         [{text: "hfmdhsmdhfhmfds", grade: 30 }]}]
```

A question div is created and then a **RubricRowV2** component is created there with the fields created based on the **rubric_fields** attribute

## **The problem:**

I'm running into issues understanding specifically in my case why updating the parent state in the component **RubricContainer** by adding another row to one of the **RubricRowV2** components causes issues. It displays the change then quicky reverts it.

Particularly it does act weird depending on which component i use, if i make the state just update so set some fixed json,

```
//update_method([{"question_id":1,"question_title":"how to abc","rubric_fields":[{"text":"a","grade":3},{"text":"a","grade":3}]}])
```

and click add field in the bottom component, it will display correctly, however if i click the add field button in top component it does not work.

Some difficulties i'm having is that i'm new to react and i am struggling to abstract documentation to my use case.

### Here are the relevant components:

**RubricContainer**

```
import RubricRowV2 from "../rubric/rubricRowV2";
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
const RubricContainer = () => {
  const DATA = [{question_id:1, question_title:'how to abc', rubric_fields : [{text: "blahblah", grade: 3 },{text: "blahblah", grade: 3 },{text: "blahblah", grade: 4 }]},
  {question_id:2, question_title:'how to eat an apple', rubric_fields : [{text: "hfmdhsmdhfhmfds", grade: 30 }]}] 
  console.log('data')

  console.log(DATA)
  const [formFields, setFormFields] = useState([
    ...DATA
  ])
  const onChangeSomeState = (newSomeState) => {
    setFormFields(newSomeState);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        {formFields.map((a,b)=>{
         return <div key={b} className='box2'>
          {/* {JSON.stringify(a)} */}
         <RubricRowV2 question={a.rubric_fields} question_index={b} update_method={onChangeSomeState} rubric_data={DATA}/>
         
         {JSON.stringify(a.rubric_fields)}
         {JSON.stringify(b)}</div>
        })}
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
export default RubricContainer
```

**RubricRowV2**

````
import '../../index.css';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import cloneDeep from 'lodash';
const RubricRowV2 = ({question, question_index, update_method, rubric_data}) => {
  
  const [formFields, setFormFields] = useState(question
  ) 
  
  const handleFormChange = (event, index) => {
    let data = cloneDeep(formFields);
    
    data[index][event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    setFormFields(data);
  }

  const submit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(formFields)
  }

  const addFields = () => {
    let object = {
      text: '',
      grade: 0
    }
    rubric_data[question_index].rubric_fields.push({text:'',grade:0})
    update_method(rubric_data)
  }

  const removeFields = (index) => {
    let data = [...formFields];
    data.splice(index, 1)
    setFormFields(data)
  }

  return (
    <div className='box2'>
      question_index {question_index}
          {formFields.map((form, index) => {
       
            return (
              <div className='rubricItem' key={index}>
                <input
                  className='formtext'
                  name='text'
                  placeholder='text'
                  onChange={event => handleFormChange(event, index)}
                  value={form.text}
                />
                <input
                  className='formtext'
                  name='grade'
                  placeholder='grade'
                  onChange={event => handleFormChange(event, index)}
                  value={form.grade}
                />
                <button className='btn' onClick={() => removeFields(index)}>Remove</button>
              </div>
            )
          })}
        <button className='btn' onClick={addFields}>Add More..</button>
      <br />
      
    </div>
  )
}
RubricRowV2.propTypes = {
}
export default RubricRowV2```

described above, i've been looking at various different, pieces of documentation or different ways of doing this, but i would prefer some understanding as to what is going wrong
````